# How do I invoke repeating instantiating a game object whilst moving it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I get the error The name 'newObject' does not exist in the current context

```
{
public GameObject platform;
public float speed = 1.0f;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("Spawning", 1f, 0f);

}

void Spawning()
{
    GameObject newObject = Instantiate(platform);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    newObject.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
}
```

I have no idea what to do

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `newObject` is declared within the `Spawning` method, so its scope is the `Spawning` method, i.e. no code outside that method can access it. You are trying to access that object from the `Update` method, which is outside it scope.

If you want to initialise a variable in one method and use it in another method then you can instead make it a field of the class, i.e. declare it at the class level rather than the method level, which means any code in the class will be able to access it.

```
public class Foo
{
    private GameObject newObject;

    // other code omitted for brevity

    void Spawning()
    {
        newObject = Instantiate(platform);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        newObject.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

You may find [this page from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/csharp-code-blocks/2-exercise-variable-scope) useful to help understand scope.

I also recommend adding some [code analysis NuGet packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=code+analysis) to your project, as these can help to highlight coding mistakes such as declaring a variable which is never used. Code analysis is your friend, and will really help you to become a better developer.